# How hide "Site content" from "cog" menu for non admin users

Tags: 2013, permissions

I've a site, and visitors (logged) are seeing the menu option "Site content" when in a list page.

[image: Menu item]

I already looked this question "[Hiding SharePoint 2013 ribon and Site Contents page for anonymous users](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/138415/hiding-sharepoint-2013-ribon-and-site-contents-page-for-anonymous-users/138429#138429)", but my test user are logged and have only read permission, how hide this option to him?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl` with `PermissionsString="FullMask"`. Then only users with full control or site collection administrators will be able to see the Gear icon for site actions, but this will hide all site actions menu .

```
<SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl ID="SPSecurityTrimmedControl1" PermissionsString="FullMask" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:SiteActions>..</SharePoint:SiteActions>
</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```

If you only want to hide Site Contents link from the Site Actions menu, try following.

```
<SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" ID="MenuItem_ViewAllSiteContents"
    Text="<%$Resources:wss,quiklnch_allcontent_15%>"
    Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_allcontentdescription%>"
    ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/allcontent32.png?rev=23"
    MenuGroupId="200"
    Sequence="240"
    UseShortId="true"
    ClientOnClickNavigateUrl="~siteLayouts/viewlsts.aspx"
    PermissionsString="FullMask"
    PermissionMode="Any" />
```

By default the `PermissionsString` property has value `ViewFormPages`, which allows read users also to see this link.

You can change it to a different permission level (eg: I have changed it to `FullMask` in above code so that only admins will see it). You can find list of permissions in the MSDN article for
[SPBasePermissions enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ms412690).

Comment: If i want to use it, then where should I place this control. In master page should I wrap some existing with this? A small example would be helpful

Comment: Yes, in the master page, you find the markup responsible for the Site Contents, and you wrap in in that control and it will trim to only those with full control (in the provided example).

Comment: Edited my answer, you can place <SharePoint:SiteActions> inside security trimmed control or try the other approach if you only want to hide site contents link.

Comment: Are you using custom mastrepage or Seattle masterpage?

Comment: Is a custom....

Comment: I don't have this options `SharePoint:SiteActions` and `SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate` on my custom master page, on Seattle too not.

Comment: If its not there you can find the control in your masterpage which renders the Site Actions menu, and put that control inside the SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl

Comment: Oops, on Seattle have, and I was editing `.html` file. I found only on side menu...

Comment: @Unnie on my `custom.master` I found only `SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl AuthenticationRestrictions="AnonymousUsersOnly"` and inside this `
wssucw:Welcome runat="server" EnableViewState="false"` in `seattle.master` have the same tag, before site actions. I put yours attributes, but didn't works.

Comment: I solved this, the attribute `PermissionsString="FullMask"` doesn't works, but `SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl` is.